# AssembleDebug: Make sure you are either running Metro (run npx react-native start) or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle'

Tags: android, react-native

i will test my app with a real device.
I run "yarn run react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res". With this comment i get an app_debug.apk file. If i send the .apk file to other people to test it, the error "Make sure you are either running Metro (run npx react-native start) or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release" occurs. I cannot start the metro server because, other people are not in the same network. I hope some can help me :)

Comment: Can you paste your app/build.gradle file?

Comment: Sure :)

Too long for the answer. Paste in pastebin :) https://pastebin.com/LXXhRCQe

Comment: you can try with ./gradlew assembleRelease. This should give you a .apk file inside android/app/build/outputs/apk

Comment: But for the release i need a paid key for a plugin. I just want the debug and share it with other people / tester

Comment: Then try ./gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: And i can use it without the metro server?